# Is there a generic way to "unprotect" static const members?

Tags: c++, protected

Sometimes am facing a situation where I am given a class (cannot modify) which has protected static members, eg

```
struct foo {
protected:
    static const int x = 42;
    static const int y = 101;
    static const int z = 404;
    // ... and more ...
};
```

and I am in the unfortunate situation that I need to access those members, not in a derived class but in other code. I wrote this:

```
struct bar : foo {
    static const int x = foo::x;
    static const int y = foo::y;
    static const int z = foo::z;
};
```

but it feels rather clumsy. On the long run class `foo` should be modified to provide access to those constants, but as long as this is not the case, i'd like to have something nicer. I could write a macro along the line of

```
int x = SOME_MACRO_VOODOO(foo,x);
```

Though, I wonder if there is a way to avoid macros. I tried many ways, for example this

```
struct f {
    protected:
    static const int x = 42;
};

template <typename T, int T::*P>
struct bar : f {
    int get_value() { return this->*P;}
};

int main() {
    bar<f,&f::x>().get_value();
}
```

Fails because `&f::x` is not a pointer to member, but just a `int *`, and of course `f::x` is not accesible:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:12:16: error: could not convert template argument '& f::x' from 'const int*' to 'int f::*'
     bar<f,&f::x>().get_value();
                ^
prog.cc:12:5: error: 'const int f::x' is protected within this context
     bar<f,&f::x>().get_value();
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~
prog.cc:3:22: note: declared protected here
     static const int x = 42;
```

Comment: There is a reason why this data is protected and not public. There is a contract that is written by the developer and you are trying to break it.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher the problem is that the contract is already "broken", it takes time and a long process to fix it and until then I need a workaround to access stuff that should be accesible but it is not

Comment: See these two articles: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm , http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html for ways to subvert access control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a [using declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration#In_class_definition). You can use `using` in the context of a class definition to import members from a base class into a derived class. If the `using` has a different access specification to the one of the member you are importing, then you effectively "change" the access specification for that member in the context of the derived class.

```
struct foo {
protected:
    static const int x = 42;
    static const int y = 101;
    static const int z = 404;
    // ... and more ...
};


struct bar : foo {
    using foo::x;
    using foo::y;
    using foo::z;
};

int main()
{
    // Should work fine
    int a = bar::x;
}
```

Comment: hum, I was sure I tried `using` and got an error complaining about `foo::x` not being a type, but this works, what a facepalm question....

Comment: I was hoping for some template magic to allow writing something like `bar<foo,x>::value` to retrieve `foo::x` (without having to `using` each member individually), though as pointed out by a different comment, there are good reasons why accessing protected data is not that easy

Comment: @user463035818: You probably test with `using x = foo::x; /*Invalid, foo::x is not a type*/`.

Comment: @user463035818 for devious template magic, see the posts I link in my comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define BYPASS_STATIC_PROTECTED( CLASS, FIELD ) \
  []()->decltype(auto){ struct cheater:CLASS { using CLASS::FIELD; }; return cheater::FIELD; }()

auto x= BYPASS_STATIC_PROTECTED( foo, x );
```

we can also do it on member fields:

```
template<class T>
struct tag_t { using type=T; };

#define BYPASS_MEMPTR_PROTECTED_HELPER( FIELD ) \
  [](auto tag){ using T=typename decltype(tag)::type; struct cheater:T { using T::FIELD; }; return &cheater::FIELD; }

#define BYPASS_MEMPTR_PROTECTED( CLASS, FIELD ) \
  BYPASS_MEMPTR_PROTECTED_HELPER(FIELD)(tag_t<CLASS>{})

#define BYPASS_PROTECTED_ON_MEMBER( FIELD ) \
  [](auto& obj )->decltype(auto) { \
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(obj)>; \
    return obj.* BYPASS_MEMPTR_PROTECTED_HELPER( FIELD )(tag_t<T>{}); \
  }
```

and similar for member functions:

```
#define BYPASS_PROTECTED_ON_METHOD( MEMBER ) \
  [](auto& obj, auto&&...args )->decltype(auto) { \
    using T = std::decay_t<decltype(obj)>; \
    return (obj.* BYPASS_MEMPTR_PROTECTED_HELPER( MEMBER )(tag_t<T>{}))( decltype(args)(args)... ); \
  }
```

[Live examples](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b25be1dead400c50).

Test code:

```
struct foo {
protected:
    static const int x = 42;
    static const int y = 101;
    static const int z = 404;
    // ... and more ...

    int member = 7;

    int method(int v) const { return -v; }
};

std::cout << BYPASS_STATIC_PROTECTED( foo, x ) << "\n";

std::cout << BYPASS_PROTECTED_ON_MEMBER( member )( f ) << "\n";

std::cout << BYPASS_PROTECTED_ON_METHOD( method )( f, 1 ) << "\n";
```